# Duration set up with CATransform3DMakeTranslation

Tags: iphone, objective-c, calayer, catransform3d

my first question on stack overflow :)

I want to make a y axis translation on a CALayer. I got a big background : 320x4000px.
The translation is working with the following code :

```
NSNumber *deplacement = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([app.session.progression floatValue] * HAUTEUR_FOND) /100];

self.backgroundLayer.transform = CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -[deplacement floatValue], 0);
```

But with this code, it's impossible to set up a duration ...

I tried with that :

```
CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position.y"];
transformAnimation.duration = 5.0f;
transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -[deplacement floatValue], 0)];
[self.backgroundLayer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"position.y"];
```

but it does not work ...

Thanks for help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, here is the answer, maybe it will help someone :)

```
NSNumber *deplacement = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:([app.session.progression floatValue] * HAUTEUR_FOND) /100];
DebugLog(@"deplacement : %@", deplacement);

if(!backgroundPositionMemo) backgroundPositionMemo = 0;

CABasicAnimation *transformAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
transformAnimation.duration = 1.0f;
transformAnimation.fromValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -backgroundPositionMemo, 0)];
transformAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:CATransform3DMakeTranslation(0, -[deplacement floatValue], 0)];
transformAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;
transformAnimation.fillMode = kCAFillModeForwards;
[self.backgroundLayer addAnimation:transformAnimation forKey:@"transform"];

backgroundPositionMemo = [deplacement floatValue];
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I've used keyPath "origin.x" instead of "transform" within similar code and your code pointed me to the right direction!